# A fatal error being thrown by JRE

Tags: compiler-errors, runtime, native, java

I am wokrking on my application in Eclipse IDE and suddenly I started getting such error when trying to run the app:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x064ed42a, pid=720, tid=5424
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x3d42a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

From the log file, I somehow realized that the bug is in native code (Problematic frame: # C [ig4icd32.dll+0x3d42a]). However, I do not know how to fix it, can anyone tell me what is the procedure for that?

Here is the log file: http://ulozto.cz/xM8uaxf/hs-err-pid720-log

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no solution for such errors unless you can identify what you are doing wrong yourself (or it is a bug). From the dll file in question I see that you are doing something with graphics, maybe 3d? The DLL description is "OpenGL(R) Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator, Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows NT(R)".

So off the top of my head I can suggest

- Check your code that you don't violate some graphics limitations
- See bug database, maybe known bug
- Update graphics drivers
- Update JRE to some newer version